# Roll over index with elastic search and serilog

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, serilog

We are using es 6.7 and serilog 7.1 in our dotnet core application.

In our logger implementation vi are using the following index "app-{0:yyyy.MM}-1" for our `ElasticsearchSinkOptions`.

This creates an index called app-2019.04-1 as expected.

However we set up an alias and a lifecycle policy which do a roll over action and creates a new index called 'app-2019.04-000002' after some conditions have been met - as expected.

The issue is that our dot net core application still logs to the first index 'app-2019.04-1'. How do we update the index format being used in the dot net core application when elastic search has performed a roll over action?

Answer (score 6):

Well I figure it out. Maybe it will help someone else. I had to log it to the alias and not the index.

For making it work you need to:

1. Create an index with format xxxx-1
2. Create an alias and ad it to the index e.g. xxxx
3. Create index pattern xxxx-*
4. Create lifecycle policy
5. Create template with indexpattern, alias and lifecycle policy
6. Make sure your indexformat in serilog is the alias.

Start logging :)